# How to resolve created events' time mismatches due to Calendar API upgrade?

Tags: python, postgresql, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

For reference, my timezone is Eastern - New York.

I am inserting events from a PostgreSQL database to a Google Calendar.  I have been using UTC-4 since early June, when I finally got my app moved from v2 to v3,  and for a couple of years in v2.  Up until the August 18 that has worked giving me the correct time.  On August 18 the time was off by one hour so I changed the setting to UTC-5.  That worked for about 2 hours and then I have had to reset it back to UTC-4.

Now today, August 21, it is off an hour again and I have set the UTC back to -5.  The events are getting inserted as they should with the exception of an event being an hour off and the UTC needing to be changed sometimes.  The system time is correct on my server.

Any ideas on what is happening?

Some of my code snippets:

```
#get an event from a PostgreSQL database to insert into a Google Calendar
curs.execute("SELECT c_event_title,c_name,c_event_date,c_event_starttime,c_event_endtime,c_department,seat_arrange,c_attendee_count from sched_421 where sched_id_421=%i;" %recnum)

mit=curs.fetchall()  # mit IS NOW ALL THE RESULTS OF THE QUERY
for myrec in mit:    #  FOR THE ONE RECORD (EVENT) IN THE QUERY RESULTS

    myend_time = time.strftime("%I:%M %p", time.strptime(str(myrec[4]),"%H:%M:%S"))
    if myend_time[0]=='0':       # Remove leading zero for 01:00 - 09:00
        myend_time = myend_time[1:]

    title        = ' - %s %s - Group:%s' %(myend_time,myrec[0],myrec[5])
    mycontent    = myrec[0]+' - '+ myrec[5]
    content      = mycontent
    where        = where_dict[room_calendar]

    #  THIS IS WHERE THE UTC IS, SOMETIMES 4 WORKS SOMETIMES 5 WORKS
    start_time   = '%sT%s-05:00' %(myrec[2],myrec[3])      #  Google format
    end_time     = '%sT%s-05:00' %(myrec[2],myrec[4])      #  Google format

    myend_time   = '%s' %myrec[4]                    #  User format (am/pm)
    seat_arrange = '\nSeating - %s' %str(myrec[6])
    attendee_count = '\nNumber of participants: %s' %str(myrec[7])
    descript       = str(myrec[0]) + '   ' + seat_arrange + attendee_count+ "\n Created By: me@somewhere.com"

# upload the event to the calendar
created_event = service.events().insert(calendarId=calendar_dict[room_calendar], body=event).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the dates you are looking at on different sides of the daylight savings switch?

[Eastern Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) is UTC-4:00 from March to November and UTC-5:00 from November to March.

Hard-coding the TZ Offset like that is a bad idea, especially in a TZ that uses daylight savings.  It would be best to store all the times as UTC and just apply the TZ information at the endpoints (data input and data display).

At the very least, you will want to have something calculate the correct TZ offset, based on the date, like a helper function or some block of logic.

I'm not sure how much control you have over the data in the database, so that would dictate which path you choose.

Ideally, you could change the 3 fields (date, start time, end time) in the database into 2 (start datetime UTC, end datetime UTC)

Comment: Thanks for your information.  If I am not mistaken, timezone is a requirement of inserting an event.  Only people on campus here are allowed to make requests so we are all in the same timezone which could allow hard coding I think.  The change seems that v2 accepted the time requested no matter what the time zone and v3 is timezone specific.  The calendar is created with a timezone also and currently Eastern shows -4 but I suspect the drop down will show -5 for Eastern after Nov. 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to change this code:

```
#  THIS IS WHERE THE UTC IS, SOMETIMES 4 WORKS SOMETIMES 5 WORKS
start_time   = '%sT%s-05:00' %(myrec[2],myrec[3])      #  Google format
end_time     = '%sT%s-05:00' %(myrec[2],myrec[4])      #  Google format
```

to (check to see if the event is in daylight savings time or not, this was not necessary with v2)

```
if bool (pytz.timezone('America/New_York').dst(datetime.datetime(myrec[2].year,myrec[2].month,myrec[2].day), is_dst=None)):
  utc_offset = '4'
else:
  utc_offset = '5'

start_time   = '%sT%s-0%s:00' %(myrec[2],myrec[3],utc_offset)
end_time     = '%sT%s-0%s:00' %(myrec[2],myrec[4],utc_offset)
```